# Left Join List<B> onto List<A> using LINQ based on 4 columns, where all 4 List<A> columns contain wildcards

Tags: c#, regex, list, linq

I have 2 in-memory lists in C#, `List<A>` and `List<B>`, where A is a class that contains wildcards in four of its properties' values; we can call those `A.prop1`, `A.prop2`, `A.prop3` and `A.prop4`.  I am trying to left join `List<B>` onto `List<A>` based off of those four `List<A>` properties that contain wildcards. The wildcards in those four properties are `%` symbols, the `%` should behave as it would in a standard T-SQL `LIKE` statement. I understand that Linq-to-SQL offers the `SQLMethods.Like` method, but I don't see anything as straightforward in Linq-to-Objects. I pieced together a Regex solution; it's working, but currently it's only joining on `A.prop1`. Here's the code:

```
var final = 
from a in ListA
from b in ListB

let matcher = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(WildcardToRegex(a.prop1))
let matches = matcher.Matches(b.prop1)

where matches.Count > 0

select new
{ 
    a.prop1,
    a.prop2,
    a.prop3,
    a.prop4,
    b.AYTD,
    b.AM,
    b.APYM
};
```

Here is the `WildcardToRegex` helper method I'm using:

```
public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
     return "^" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(pattern).
         Replace("\\*", ".*").
         Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
}
```

So I added more matchers, but it just gets stuck in an infinite loop. I tried stepping through it to see what's going on, but can't make much sense of it. Here's the code where I add the last three matchers, which gets stuck in a loop:

```
var final = 
from a in ListA
from b in ListB

let matcher = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(WildcardToRegex(a.prop1))
let matches = matcher.Matches(b.prop1)

let matcher2 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(WildcardToRegex(a.prop2))
let matches2 = matcher2.Matches(b.prop2)

let matcher3 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(WildcardToRegex(a.prop3))
let matches3 = matcher3.Matches(b.prop3)    

let matcher4 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(WildcardToRegex(a.prop4))
let matches4 = matcher4.Matches(b.prop4)

where matches.Count > 0
where matches2.Count > 0
where matches3.Count > 0
where matches4.Count > 0

select new
{ 
    a.prop1,
    a.prop2,
    a.prop3,
    a.prop4,
    b.AYTD,
    b.AM,
    b.APYM
};
```

**EDIT**

The two lists look like this:

List A

> ```
> 4% , 000 , 100, 777
> 5200, 111, 333, 42%
> 4400, % , 2%, %
> 5%, %, %, 6%
> %, %, % , %
> ```

List B

> ```
> 4200 , 000 , 100, 777 , $520, $734
> 4611 , 000 , 100, 777 , $80, $6
> 5200, 111, 333, 426, $25, $40
> 5200, 111, 333, 420, $5, $10
> 4400, 387 , 288, 000, $200, $320
> 5000, 000, 555, 600, $42, $57
> ```

And the final product / joined table I am aiming for would look like this:

> ```
> 4% , 000 , 100, 777, $600, $740
> 5200, 111, 333, 42%, $30, $50
> 4400, % , 2%, %, $200, $320
> 5%, %, %, 6%, $42, $57
> %, %, % , %, $872, $1167   //everything in list B
> ```

Comment: When you say you want to "left join list B onto A" do you mean that you want all items from B regardless of whether any match A, or the other way around?  Or do you really mean an inner join (only return the matching rows)?  Also, your question text says that `%` is a wildcard character, but your code uses `?`.  Which is the correct one?

Comment: Let class A encapsulate the logic whether a string matches its properties. In fact, A is a *specification* that could have a method like `IsSatisfiedBy()`.

Comment: @BrianRogers  I actually mean left join. I only want to bring over items from ListB if they have a match in ListA.  The correct one is %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's make it easier to do the wildcard matching you want to do in LINQ-to-objects so that it feels more like SQL.

In your question you said you want `%` characters to work like SQL wildcards, but your `WildcardToRegex` method is currently using file system wildcards `*` and `?`.  So we need to fix that.  Also, I think it makes more sense to have the method return a `Regex` object rather than a string pattern, since you will always have to wrap the pattern in a `Regex` anyway in order to use it. Here is the method with those changes:

```
public static Regex WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
    return new Regex("^" + Regex.Escape(pattern)
        .Replace("%", ".*")
        .Replace("_", ".") + "$");
}
```

Now, to test for a match on a particular wildcard string, we don't actually need to get a list of matches and count them.  We can just use `Regex.IsMatch()` instead, for example:

```
if (WildcardToRegex("foo%").IsMatch("foo bar"))
    Console.WriteLine("got a match!");
```

But the above is still a little verbose.  We can wrap it in a `Like` extension method to make it super easy to use:

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static bool Like(this string target, string pattern)
    {
        if (target == null || pattern == null) return false;
        return WildcardToRegex(pattern).IsMatch(target);
    }

    public static Regex WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
    {
        ...  (same code from above)  ...
    }
}
```

This will allow us to do this:

```
if ("foo bar".Like("foo%"))
    Console.WriteLine("got a match!");
```

OK, now that we have the wildcard matching down, we just need to write the query.  In LINQ-to-objects you can do a left join by using a `.Where( ... ).DefaultIfEmpty()` construction.  This means that all items from list A will appear a least once in the result, joined with list B wherever there is a match.  Where there is no match, all the selected properties of item B will be null, so if those properties are value types (e.g. `int`, `decimal`, `bool`, etc.), they need to be made nullable in the result.

Here is what the resulting query would look like:

```
var result = from a in listA
             from b in listB
             .Where(b => 
                 b.prop1.Like(a.prop1) && 
                 b.prop2.Like(a.prop2) && 
                 b.prop3.Like(a.prop3) && 
                 b.prop4.Like(a.prop4)).DefaultIfEmpty()  // left join
             select new
             {
                 a.prop1,
                 a.prop2,
                 a.prop3,
                 a.prop4,
                 b?.AM,     // these need to be nullable if they are value types
                 b?.AYTD,
                 b?.APYM
             };
```

Here is a working demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z1smDh

If you want to sum the values from list B then you need to use a `group by` clause, with `Sum()` for each property as shown below:

```
var result = from a in listA
             from b in listB
             .Where(b => 
                 b.prop1.Like(a.prop1) && 
                 b.prop2.Like(a.prop2) && 
                 b.prop3.Like(a.prop3) && 
                 b.prop4.Like(a.prop4)).DefaultIfEmpty()  // left join
             group b by a into g
             select new
             {
                 g.Key.prop1,
                 g.Key.prop2,
                 g.Key.prop3,
                 g.Key.prop4,
                 AM = g.Sum(b => b?.AM),
                 AYTD = g.Sum(b => b?.AYTD),
                 APYM = g.Sum(b => b?.APYM)
             };
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nM9iAa

Comment: wow this is amazing. thank you. I'm going to test it etc. before marking as answer. thank you

Comment: i loaded this into my program. It does not sum ListB properties like it should. Take a look at the Lists examples I just edited into the questions above.

Comment: I just confirmed, this solution does not meet the criteria. It has to take the sums of the listB items. The list B items are dollar amounts.

Comment: You never mentioned anything about summing the terms until now.  If you want to do that, you need a `group by` clause with `Sum()` just as you would for SQL.  I've updated my answer to show how.  (See the last section.)

Comment: I know , that was my bad. I just saw your edited response. I'm confirming now.

Comment: is there a way to change the extension method to let it accept integers? I had to convert ListB to integer so the sum extension method will work, but now the Like extension method isn't working because it only accepts strings.

Comment: To make it work, I just went back and converted my Lists and Class types accordingly instead.  This answer is perfect. Thanks so much for your help. We replaced Microsoft Report Designer with a program I wrote to produce my company's income statements. Before I had this, I was doing a separate SQL query for every record in ListA and returning the balance amounts for each account one row at a time. Now I get the account mapping list (listA) and run 1 SQL query (listB), and do a single join. This will make take my program down from about 1 min per report to about 5 secs. Thanks so much again.